# Can I use an external flash with an iPhone?

Tags: flash, iphone

I do interior photography occasionally. I'd like to replace my Canon M50 with the iPhone 13 Pro Max but I'm concerned about an external flash.

- Is it possible to use an external flash with iPhone?
- What's the best external flash dedicated?
- I already own a great Canon Speedlite 430EX II. Can I use it with the iPhone?

Comment: You want to replace 14bit RAW with 12bit "RAW"?

Comment: @RomeoNinov yeah, for my use cases there are no much differences.

Comment: Hm, AFAIK interior photos are usually with high dynamic range and you need to recover highlights and light the shadows. And those 2 bits may make the difference.

Comment: @RomeoNinov As I said, those 2 bits don't make any differences for my use cases  but what it could be a difference to me is using a good flash light. Do you know if there's a really good flash light to connect to the iPhone? I was watching the Profoto A10 or B10. Area they comparable with the Canon Speedlight 430EX II?

Comment: This might work for you.  https://www.innovatronix.com/product/innovatronix-cpflash-550w-tri-function-off-camera-flash-for-smartphones-dslrs-or-mirrorless-cameras-and-video-lighting-fx/

Comment: Have you consider using LED light? https://www.amazon.it/s?k=LED+light&rh=n%3A473475031&dc&__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&qid=1632324611&rnid=1640607031&ref=sr_nr_n_6

Comment: Have you considered seeing what the 13's low light performance is like first? My old 6S beats my DSLR for 'automagic' HDRs [the nikon beats the phone after some work in Photoshop, but not straight out of the camera]. The 12 was really good in low light & the 13's lenses/aperture/sensors are bigger still.

Comment: [Will Off Camera Flash Make The iPhone a Professional Camera?](https://fstoppers.com/apps/will-camera-flash-make-iphone-professional-camera-514314) and [Godox Made an Off-Camera Flash and Transmitter for Smartphones](https://petapixel.com/2017/07/22/godox-made-off-camera-flash-transmitter-smartphones/)

Comment: @MichaelC, thanks I needed [a link](https://medium.com/profoto/the-tech-transformation-of-a-traditional-hardware-company-ecc8a2de72f1) in that fstoppers article. :) But the Godox A1 is not a solution for the OP: the A1+app doesn't work with iOS 13 or any iPhones from the 11 onward, and the A1 is discontinued. Also, sync speed would be 1/45s.

Comment: I'm not an apple user and was not aware that Godox  has apparently given up on updating their app to keep up with the iPhone.

Answer (score 4):

> I do interior photography occasionally. I'd like to replace my Canon
> M50 with the iPhone 13 Pro Max but I'm concerned about an external
> flash.

You should be. The rolling electronic shutters in most phone cameras eliminates using flash at all, since it [lowers the camera's flash sync speed](https://www.dpreview.com/articles/5816661591/electronic-shutter-rolling-shutter-and-flash-what-you-need-to-know) down to roughly 1/30s or slower (on my iPhone8, it was 1/25s). It's why the "flash" on most phone cameras is really a continuous LED light, rather than a Xenon bulb strobe.

That LED 'flash' also cannot trip "dumb" optical slaves.

> Is it possible to use an external flash with iPhone?

It is, but at this time, the only company that's [cracked the problem](https://medium.com/profoto/the-tech-transformation-of-a-traditional-hardware-company-ecc8a2de72f1) of syncing an off-camera radio-triggered flash with an iPhone camera is **Profoto**. Which costs a kidney (e.g., the Profoto A10 speedlight is US$1100). But the [Protofo Camera app](https://profoto.com/us/profoto-camera) for iOS and Android lets you use Profoto lights with your iPhone camera via their AirX technology at any shutter speed.

AFAIK, at the time of writing this (Sept. 2021), nobody else has managed to correctly sync a strobe with a smartphone camera.

There was [the Godox A1](https://www.dpreview.com/news/1259675135/godox-a1-smartphone-flash-trigger-officially-released-costs-70) transmitter/flash which communicated with the phone via Bluetooth, but it stopped working after iOS 13 and the iPhone 11 came out, and has since been discontinued. It had a very narrow window of usage, anyway, because, unlike Profoto, they never found a way around the sync speed issue, and the Godox Photos app itself (which was what you had to use as your camera app) was badly designed and wonky. I detailed using one in [this 2017 dpreview post](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/60179238).

> What's the best external flash dedicated?

There is no such thing as a dedicated flash for iPhone, since the iPhone has no physical flash sync connectors on it.  And all the "flash" units that can be connected via a lightning port are really continuous LED lights.

> I already own a great Canon Speedlite 430EX II. Can I use it with the iPhone?

No. Profoto does not make add-on receivers for speedlights for the Air system. And the only wireless protocol the 430EX II "speaks" is the Canon "smart" optical one.

My advice would be to consider using continuous video (LED) lighting instead of strobes with your iPhone, or if flash photography is vital to what you need to accomplish, that you not move entirely to an iPhone, but also keep a camera with a flash hotshoe in the bag.

Comment: I’m interested in Profoto A10 or B10 if they can fit this purpose. Do you think they can replace my Canon 430EX-III for my use cases? Is the Profoto A10 enough? Alternative, what continuous light do you suggest?

Comment: @KaMZaTa, Shopping questions are [forbidden on stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) as they're not a great fit in the goal of finding long-term permanent answers for a wide audience. I think you might have better luck asking on [the dpreview forums](https://www.dpreview.com/forums), which is all about the shopping as they are owned by Amazon. :) As for an A10 being "enough" vs. a 430EX III-RT? It's overkill; more like an EL-1.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know anything specific that directly connects to any phone.

Probably the most realistic solution is to use continuous light. There are many affordable solutions. Even a normal desktop lamp.

---

For a moment I was thinking that an external flash with an optical slave could work; after all, you can use it on a DSLR camera to some extent, even with a TTL flash with a dumb optical slave. You can add some cardboard to block the light from the DSLR flash from hitting your subject and only bounce it to the optical sensor if the flash is in range.

But a cellphone flash is soo close to the lens that you can not add that. Besides that, there is no guarantee that the optical slave would recognize the light as a triggering light.

Comment: The LED "flash" on an iPhone will not trigger "dumb" optical slaves.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Potech's TricCam. I use my speedlites with it on my iPhone 13. Sync speed is 1/60th. You have to use TricCam's app, which costs about $8.00. The device itself costs under $60.00. Once you can fire one speedlite, you can set the up others as optical slaves. The LED flash on the iPhone will trigger an optical slave, but it has to be placed about a half inch away from it to see it.